# Qt - How to write "more" data to QProcess?

Tags: python, c++, qt, virtualenv

I am facing an issue I faced a few times so far.
The issue in question just gets solved by itself every time, without me understanding what is causing it
So what happens is that I start a python virtual environment from my c++ code. That works, afterwards by using the write function I am able to write stuff in that environment. This also works perfectly fine so far. However I am unable to write my last command to the process.
I though about maybe some buffer being full but I didn't really find anything about a buffer in the Qt docs

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
static QStringList params;
QProcess *p = new QProcess();

params<<"-f"<<"-c"<<"python2"<< "/home/John/Desktop/python.log";
qDebug()<<"parameters: "<<params;

qDebug()<<"going to write";
p->start("script", params);
qDebug()<<"Turning on new user process...";
while(!p->waitForStarted())
{qDebug()<<"waiting for virtualenv to be ready";}
successFailWrite = p->write("import imp;\n");
while(!p->waitForBytesWritten());
successFailWrite = p->write("foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/recognitionClass.py');\n");
while(!p->waitForBytesWritten());
successFailWrite = p->write("from myTest import recognitionClass;\n");
while(!p->waitForBytesWritten());
successFailWrite = p->write("myClassObj = recognitionClass();\n");
if(successFailWrite !=-1)
{qDebug()<<"OK written";}
while(!p->waitForBytesWritten());
successFailWrite = p->write("habelahabela\n");
if(successFailWrite !=-1)
{qDebug()<<"OK written";}

QString name = "John";
QString processNewUserParameter= "print myClassObj.addNewUser("+ name +");\n";
QByteArray processNewUserParameterByteArr= processNewUserParameter.toUtf8();
p->write(processNewUserParameterByteArr);
```

I keep a log file which contains what is being written to the python virtualenv and what is being printed

```
Script started on Son 27 Aug 2017 20:09:52 CEST
import imp;
foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/recognitionClass.py');
from myTest import recognitionClass;
myClassObj = recognitionClass();
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import imp;
>>> foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/recognit
<myTest', '/home/John/recogniti                         onClass.py');
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py:43: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  DeprecationWarning)
>>> from myTest import recognitionClass;
>>> myClassObj = recognitionClass();
>>>
```

It does pront "OK written" twice, which on one side proves that I successfully wrote my commands to the process, yet I can't see anything.

As you can see the test sentence "habelahabela" doesn't get written neither.
Does anybody have an idea about what I may be doing wrong?
I know that I am writing my commands to quickly to the environment. Because as you can see I start by writing "import imp", it then gets buffered and a little later the buffer gets flushed and the virtualenv executes the command (this is why you see it twice).

Does anybody see why I can't see the test-sentence and -more importantly- my actual command `"print myClassObj.addNewUser("+ name +");\n"`  being printed to the virtual environment?

Thanks

Comment: That buffer is some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html). You may want to handle the [readyRead](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) & [readyReadStandardOutput](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput) Qt signals

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ok thx for the clarification, what do you suggest for my issue?

Comment: Spend several hours reading documentation. Also read a textbook about [Operating Systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no sense in writing `while(!p->waitForBytesWritten());`. `waitForBytesWritten` already blocks your thread without a `while` loop and, as the name states, waits until bytes are written. It returns `false` only if there are either timeout or an error. In the first case you should give it more time to write bytes. In the second case you should fix the error and only then try again.
The same holds for `waitForStarted` and all other Qt functions starting with "waitFor...".

So the usage looks like:

```
if(!p->waitForBytesWritten(-1)) // waits forever until bytes ARE written
{
   qDebug() << "Error while writing bytes";
}
```

***Regarding the question:*** I believe the problem (or at least a part of it) is that you write your last 2 messages into `p`, but you neither wait for `bytesWritten()` signal, nor use `waitForBytesWritten()` blocking function. Although, there is probably no error occuring (because `p->write(...)` does not return -1 at that point), however it does not mean that your message is written yet. In a nutshell, wait for `bytesWritten()` signal...

`QProcess` inherits from `QIODevice`, so I recommend to look [its docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write-2) and learn about it a bit more.